# Why WCF Service stops concurrency while transferring large amount of text data (around 20 MB)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

We have a WCF Service which transfers large amount of data. All of sudden our service which used to take only around a second started taking around 20 minutes to execute. When we did some investigation, we found that that a service call was getting executed on server after around 20 minutes it is sent from client. We have configured our service to be concurrent up-to 500 calls. Following are our config file settings for this.

```
 <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="TransferServiceBehavior" >
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="500" maxConcurrentSessions="500" maxConcurrentInstances="500"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Then we reduced the amount of data that service was transferring and its concurrency was back in action. So our problem is that our service stops being concurrent when we transfer large amount of data around 20 MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default settings for service throttling are as below based on the Processor Count.

MaxConcurrentSessions: default is 100 * ProcessorCount
MaxConcurrentCalls: default is 16 * ProcessorCount
MaxConcurrentInstances: default is the total of the above two, which follows the same pattern as before

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2009/07/26/wcf-4-higher-default-throttling-settings-for-wcf-services.aspx

As you are trying to pass heavy stream of data, you can also try implementing MTOM-Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (MTOM) message encoding with a WSHttpBinding.

Comment: MTOM is not helpful in our case as our service is not sending data other than text.